# My app is getting crashed on UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc

I am working on file sharing on my iOS App, I am new to `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. I do not know why my app is crashing.

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.image"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
documentPicker.delegate = self;
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

App is crashing on the highlighted lines.

Has anyone done this previously? I want to do the same like the attachment below [image]

Comment: Please show the stack trace from the crashed thread.

Comment: [UIDocumentPickerViewController _commonInitWithCompletion:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UIDocumentPickerViewController.m:66
2015-03-27 17:40:24.282 DocPick[3285:73604] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: have a look at this, [Entitlements.plist in Xamarin.iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856432/3482732)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

See `Prerequisite` section on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451):

> Before your app can use the document picker, you must turn on the
>   iCloud Documents capabilities in Xcode

[image]

Let me know if this solve your problem!

Answer (score 4):

**swift 3.0** you can select all document.

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", "com.apple.iwork.keynote.key","public.image", "com.apple.application", "public.item","public.data", "public.content", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.movie", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.video", "public.audio", "public.text", "public.data", "public.zip-archive", "com.pkware.zip-archive", "public.composite-content", "public.text"], in: .import)

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Even with all entitlements set up, this still happens every now and then, when running **on a device** (not simulator).
The best solution I've found so far is:

1. Stop the app from Xcode.
2. Launch the app from the device (tap the app icon on the home screen...)
3. Navigate in your app, in order to open the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.
4. Once open, you can launch the app again in Xcode and `UIDocumentPickerViewController` will init as intended.

From my experience, it will work until you install a TestFlight build. Sometimes you'll need to do this again after restarting Xcode.
This certainly looks like a bug with installing entitlements on the device.

(Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.2)

Answer (score 2):

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```