# iOS: UIDocumentPickerViewController - missing the iCloud entitlement error

Tags: ios, icloud

I get this error when I want to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController`:

> Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?

I enabled **iCloud** in the **Capabilities** and I have entitlement with key `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers` set to array with one element `iCloud.${CFBundleIdentifier}`.

What can cause this error, especially when it worked earlier?

The error shows document picker but it happens when I try to initialise `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.

It has something with bundle version, this error happened when I changed the version number, when I change it to the previous one it was ok. Does anybody understand that?

Comment: Did u solve it yet? i got the same issue.

Comment: @DannyHo Unfortunately I have no idea what caused this error.

Comment: I thought somewhere in Apple documentation it said that UIDocumentPickerViewController doesn't work with iCloud. I've actually created my own user interface instead. Can anyone verify this for me or correct me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300772/my-app-is-getting-crashed-on-uidocumentpickerviewcontroller