# Importing of documents via UIDocumentMenuViewController in iOS 9 stuck at loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidocumentmenuvc

It works properly in iOS 8, but in iOS 9 it gets stuck when selecting a document file, the image of being stuck is below:

[image]

Code:

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.item", (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeContent, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeData, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypePackage, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeDiskImage, @"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
importMenu.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300772/my-app-is-getting-crashed-on-uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/29889034#29889034

Comment: Can't use uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, it doesn't have an option to add  new items aside from the cloud storages, the code above are shortened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is an issue with iOS 9 itself because we definitely followed what was instructed in the apple documentation and also in what results we can find in the web.

This only happens when you don't merge after you signed in your iCloud account.