# iOS8 crash when try to use UIDocumentMenuViewController

Tags: xamarin, ios8, xamarin.forms, icloud

I use Xamarin.Forms to create iOS app and I use UIDocumentMenuViewController to Access iCloud file.

When I run program on iOS9+ program is run normally, But when I try my program with iOS8 emulator program is crash on

```
new UIDocumentMenuViewController(allowedUTIs, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
```

and message is saying

```
'Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?'
```

What wrong with my app and how can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have enabled the iCloud Entitlements as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_property_lists/#Entitlements.plist).

This is even mentioned in the [official iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014451):

> Before your app can use the document picker, you must turn on the iCloud Documents capabilities

If you haven't done so already, simply create a new `Entitlements.plist` file in the root of your project. Then simply enable the `iCloud` option.

Comment: I already enable iCloud in entitlements.plist and already add iCloud container to app ID.
Is there another thing that I may missed?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have linked Entitlements.plist to your project...

I dont know why, but by default Entitlements.plist is not linked, you can do the same by going to option of project and assign custom Entitlement like this!

[image]