# which is this controller in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, controller, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, uidocumentmenuvc

I was surfing some site in safari. it was attachment button. when I clicked on that button. it showed this controller. Can any1 tell me which is this default functionality safari provide. it is dere in various apps too like slack.

its shows icloud/google drive/dropbox all three in one action.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `UIDocumentPickController`. Check the apple developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller)

```
let documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And delegate

```
    // MARK: - UIDocumentPickerDelegate Methods

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.import {
            // This is what it should be
//            self.newNoteBody.text = String(contentsOfFile: url.path!)
        }
    }
```

**After adding the code you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29347899/7456236) post too or else you will get an exception**. You should go to capabilities & turn iCloud capabilities on. Add icloud containers also there

`UIDocumentMenuController` is the same as `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. But its deprecated. check the developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentmenuviewcontroller) here

Comment: I have used this it doesnt give me this controller.  its ```UIDocumentMenuViewController```

Comment: @vaibby yeah `UIDocumentMenuViewController` is the deprecated version of `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Comment: its not deprecated. it is dere from iOS 8.

Comment: @vaibby Check developer documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentmenuviewcontroller 
They say to use UIDocumentPickerViewController instead of UIDocumentMenuViewController

Comment: is ```UIDocumentPickerViewController``` can give me this controller?

Comment: @vaibby Yes it will

Comment: @vaibby to be clear this is being deprecated in iOS 11 which is still in Beta. If you are targeting iOS 10 you should still use `UIDocumentMenuViewController` and use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` on iOS 11 when it is available.