# UIDocumentPickerViewController is failing in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, icloud, icloud-documents

I have a document picker implemented that works on iOS 11+ but is failing on iOS 10.

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *pickerViewController = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:documentTypes
                                                                                                              inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
```

This is the code where it is crashing with

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInternalInconsistencyException’, reason: ‘Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set"

I've already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29300772/7504076) which was crashing with the same error. I've done all that was asked in it but am still crashing at this point, but only on iOS 10, not on any version higher.

Is there some plist key, that wasn't explicitly mentioned that I need to set to get rid of this?